# Python 3.x ctypes Windows API call fails with ERROR_BAD_LENGTH (24)

Tags: python-3.x, winapi, ctypes

My calls to `Proces32First` are failing with an ERROR_BAD_LENGTH (24) error code and I don't know why.  Here's my code that's failing:

```
def get_explorer_pid(self):
    class ENTRY(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [('size', wintypes.DWORD),
                ('usage', wintypes.DWORD),
                ('pid', wintypes.DWORD),
                ('heap', wintypes.LPVOID),
                ('mid', wintypes.DWORD),
                ('threads', wintypes.DWORD),
                ('ppid', wintypes.DWORD),
                ('pri', wintypes.LONG),
                ('flags', wintypes.DWORD),
                ('exe', wintypes.CHAR)]

    entry = ENTRY()
    entry.size = ctypes.sizeof(ENTRY)
    error = ctypes.WinDLL('Kernel32').GetLastError
    snapshot = ctypes.WinDLL('Kernel32').CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(
        0x00000002, None)
    test = ctypes.WinDLL('Kernel32').Process32First(snapshot, ctypes.byref(entry))
    print('error: ', error(test))
```

I'm not sure what's wrong.  I thought I followed the API docs well...

Comment: you wrong define `ENTRY` and error `ERROR_BAD_LENGTH` related to this (invalid value in `entry.size`)

Comment: `'exe', wintypes.CHAR` - this is `char exe[260]` array

Comment: Hey @RbMm.  I'm sorry, I'm dense and not fully understanding what you mean.  So, `'exe', wintypes.CHAR` is wrong?  What should I do to correct it?

Comment: here must be not single char but array or 260 chars

Comment: Thanks, @RbMm!  I got it working with the following code:

`class EXE(ctypes.Structure):
            _fields_ = [('c', wintypes.CHAR)]`
`('exe', EXE * 260)]`

Comment: This also works: `('exe', wintypes.CHAR * 260)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's working code with comments on fixes.  This works on 32- and 64-bit Python:

```py
import ctypes
from ctypes import wintypes

ULONG_PTR = wintypes.LPARAM  # ULONG_PTR type changes size 32-/64-bit.  LPARAM does too.
MAX_PATH = 260               # Needed for "exe" array to define correctly
TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS = 0x2
ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES = 18

# Use the wide version of the structure with Python to get Unicode strings for "exe"
class PROCESSENTRY32W(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [('size', wintypes.DWORD),
                ('usage', wintypes.DWORD),
                ('pid', wintypes.DWORD),
                ('heap', ULONG_PTR),          # Use correct type for 32-/64-bit
                ('mid', wintypes.DWORD),
                ('threads', wintypes.DWORD),
                ('ppid', wintypes.DWORD),
                ('pri', wintypes.LONG),
                ('flags', wintypes.DWORD),
                ('exe', wintypes.WCHAR * MAX_PATH)]  # Correct way to declare array

entry = PROCESSENTRY32W()
entry.size = ctypes.sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32W)

dll = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32',use_last_error=True)  # Ensures capturing last error

# Declaring parameter types and return values helps catch errors.
# HANDLE is different on 32-/64-bit as well and can get truncated.
dll.CreateToolhelp32Snapshot.argtypes = wintypes.DWORD,wintypes.DWORD
dll.CreateToolhelp32Snapshot.restype = wintypes.HANDLE
dll.Process32FirstW.argtypes = wintypes.HANDLE, ctypes.POINTER(PROCESSENTRY32W)
dll.Process32FirstW.restype = wintypes.BOOL
dll.Process32NextW.argtypes = wintypes.HANDLE, ctypes.POINTER(PROCESSENTRY32W)
dll.Process32NextW.restype = wintypes.BOOL

snapshot = dll.CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0)
if not dll.Process32FirstW(snapshot, entry):
    print('error:', ctypes.get_last_error()) # gets error captured by ctypes call
else:                                        # not last Win32 call in general.
    print(entry.exe)

while True:
    if not dll.Process32NextW(snapshot, entry):
        err = ctypes.get_last_error()
        if err == ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES:
            break
        else:
            print('error:',err)
    print(entry.exe)
```